# Android application and Application server

Tags: android

I want to develop a basic form application which records datas into a sql server. However, it is commercial work so i need to use an application server for security reasons. I searched and discovered that android can connect to a sql server via a open source library but i'm not sure how to use an application server with these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a webservice layer on you application sever and consume these on the android client.
Connecting to DB directly is not advisable

Comment: Can you please give some examples how can i build webservice and app server? Because, before my attempts about db connections, i create one class and hole db access information in it so it can directly connect db so what is differences of that and how can i do it? I am still searching and if you have a some useful source or example about webservice and application server, can you send me?

Comment: search for RESTful webservices and you would get enough content.